# IE8 error on GoogleChart redraw function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

I am using the Google Charts API to draw several ComboCharts utilizing the arrayToDataTable routine.  Everything loads fine but an error occurs (*in IE8 only*) if I try to redraw any of the charts.

I first noticed this when triggering a redraw of the charts using JQuery's $( window ).resize but the issue is present even if I just execute two back-to-back chart.draw functions.

Any ideas...

- What is causing this error?
- How can I fix it?

**Script Error from IE8 (repeated multiple times):**

```
format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js
```

Here is sample code that will reproduce the error in IE8.  Resize the window to trigger the error:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Graph Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var opt = {
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      axisTitlesPosition: 'none',
      enableInteractivity: 'false',
      hAxis: {textPosition: 'none'},
      vAxis: {textPosition: 'none', maxValue: 11, minValue: 6, gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}, baselineColor: 'transparent'},
      lineWidth: 1,
      bar: {groupWidth:'75%'},
      seriesType: "bars",
     series: {1: {type: "line"}},
      chartArea: {'width': '90%', 'height': '90%'},
      colors: ['#4D8C8C', '#a7a7a7'],
      backgroundColor: '#d3eeee'
}


var myArray = [
    ['ID', 'Value', {role: 'style'}, 'Rec', {role: 'certainty'}],
    [1, 8, '#FF0000', 10, false],
    [2, 7, '#FF0000', 10, false],
    [2, 10, '#FF0000', 10, false]
    ];

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawChart(myArray,opt)});

 function drawChart(arr,opt) {
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
    chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, opt);
  }

$(document).ready(function() {

$( window ).resize(function() {
    drawChart(myArray,opt);
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: auto; height: 50px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new chart object each time, try redrawing the existing one:

```
function drawChart(arr,opt) {
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, opt);
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        chart.draw(data, opt);
    });
}
```

Comment: That worked well for the IE8 error.  I ended up moving the chart initialization ("var chart = new google.visualization....") to its own init function and then call only the chart.draw to redraw on window resize.  The problem now (IE8 only) is that the resize works on expanding the window but **not** decreasing the window size.  Weird.  The chart grows appropriately when increasing window width but does not shrink down when decreasing window width.

Comment: Try adding a call to `chart.clearChart` before the `chart.draw` call inside the resize handler.

Comment: Regrettably, that didn't work either.  Specifically, when I increase the window size, the graph resizes appropriately in IE8.  But when I decrease the window size (i.e. width), the graph does not resize at all.  There are no errors reported.  It just doesn't fire the resize action I expect on decreasing the window size. Everything continues to work fine in FireFox.  This is only an IE8 issue so far.  Unfortunately, this is the target browser I am programming against.

Comment: Hmm...what happens if you set `overflow: hidden` on the chart's container div?  What about `width: 100%`?

Comment: IE8 SOLUTION:  Thanks asgallant for sticking with me on this one!  Your diligence paid off!  Adding `overflow: hidden` to the style element of the `DIV` tag containing the chart worked.  Specifically, in IE8, adding the `overflow` style allows the chart to resize when decreasing the window width and increasing the window width.  No errors reported.  Changing the width of the chart does not affect anything (i.e. you can set to whatever).  Thanks again!  Hope this helps someone else too.  Weird that it was such a subtle issue on decreasing window only.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that the chart was preventing the document's net width from decreasing, and it might be that IE8 conflates document width window width.